# Visual Studio working slow with increasing revisions of Tortoise Svn

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn, repository

As the number of revisions increase with each commits, the Visual Studio applications starts working slow. As an when I created a new repository and pasted the current application folder, the same application is running very speedily after a new checkout from new repository.

Is there a way to clean-up svn directories or temp files. Or any maintaining tips would be great to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes no sense at all. At least: I can assure you that this has nothing (absolutely nothing, seriously) to do with svn. Because a working copy doesn't store the history of files.

I suspect it's a problem with your *.ncb file - just delete that file (it will get recreated automatically).